# How to set apache2.4 custom log

Tags: apache, logging

I cannot find how to set a custom log location for my site, using Apache2.4.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
   ....
   php_value error_reporting 2047
   php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
   php_flag short_open_tag off

   DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

   <Directory /var/www/ablog>
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All

     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
    </Directory>

    CustomLog ./logs/blog_log common

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This will result in the following error:

```
(2)No such file or directory: AH02297: Cannot access directory '/etc/apache2/logs/' for log file './logs/blog_log' defined at /var/www/ablog/vhost.conf:31
```

Comment: Does /etc/apache2/logs exist, and is it writeable by the user you're running apache as - are you running it as root? I might try creating /etc/apache2/logs/logs/ just in case it's somehow ending up with two /logs/ there, but I'd guess not. You could also try giving CustomLog an absolute path to somewhere you can definitely write, e.g. /tmp/blog_log, and see what owner and permissions the file is created with.

Comment: It exists and is writeable. But nothing from this site is being populated inside here. I see though, this is purely a permissions issues/file does not exists. I will play with this idea, thank you.

Comment: The absolute path works, if you want to add as correct answer please do.

Answer (score 1):

For example, the following two sets of directives have exactly the same effect:

## CustomLog with format nickname

LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

## CustomLog with explicit format string

CustomLog "logs/access_log" "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"

Details are here:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

Comment: That doesn't look like it addresses OP's specific error.

Comment: your conf shows `CustomLog ./logs/blog_log common`

change it to `CustomLog "./logs/blog_log common"`

Comment: Thanks again Enzamam: `CustomLog takes two or three arguments, a file name, a custom log format string or format name, and an optional "env=" or "expr=" clause (see docs)`